# Replicating Facebook's "Older Posts/Comments" thing

Tags: php, javascript, css, ajax

On Facebook when you, for instance, scroll down your Wall, you hit "the bottom" where you can press the Older Posts button and a couple dozen more posts appear. Can anyone give me an idea on how i can replicate that on my webpage? 
I am new to webprogramming and i'm not sure how this works, i don't even know how and what to search on the web to be honest, no clue where to start looking.

So any suggestions, links are appreciated. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search returned this tutorial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-twitter-like-load-more-widget/

From the page itself:

- The server needs to be running PHP5 so that we can use PHP5′s JSON functions.
- We’ll be pulling database records from a WordPress “posts” MySQL table. What’s great about the code provided is that you may use it with any database system; all you’ll need to do is modify the MySQL query and the JSON properties used by jQuery or MooTools.
- The client must support javascript.
- We’re using MooTools 1.2.3 Core and More 1.2.3.1. If jQuery is the preferred framework, jQuery 1.3.2 and Ariel Flesler’s ScrollTo plugin.